# The other icon on map disappears when pushpin(layer) is close to the icon(Bing map V8)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bing-maps

I am using Bing map version 8, earlier with version 7 used entities, now we use layers and create a new layer and add pushpins to that layer and then add the layer to the map.

But, in a situation when an sea port icon is there and a pushpin emerges very close to it, it hides the icon and pushpin stands visible.I want both icon and pin to stay visible. Please help.

var pinLayer = new Microsoft.Maps.Layer();

//Created pins

pinLayer.add(pin); //added the pin to layer

//

map.layers.insert(pinLayer); //Added the layer to map

[Earlier in v7 (using entities)-](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7aaH.png)

[Now in V8, the same icon of airport is not visible. I want it to show up.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7rDN.png)

Comment: Is the port icon a pushpin? Can you provide more info, it isn't clear. Have you tried the experimental branch to see if it happens there. All the bug fixes in the experimental branch are being added to the main release branch early next week.

Comment: No it is a general airport icon(actually) for any airport on bing map. When any pushpin is created close to that airport icon(kind of overlap situation) then pushpin hides the airport icon. can you please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you talking about the airport icon that is automatically added by Bing Maps? If so, this is to be expected as it is a map label which is lower priority than your data. Bing Maps uses vector labels and label collision to hide map labels which are overlapped by pushpins to keep the map view nice and clean. If you would prefer to disable the vector labels simply add the following map option when loading: `liteMode: true`

You can find out more about vector labels in Bing Maps V8 here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt750538.aspx

Comment: Tried litemode :true , still no help..when a pushpin gets created , if there is an airport icon or any other street name too .. then it disappears after pushpin is created over there. Pls help i need an urgent fix. Really URGENT

Comment: Check images added in summary.

Comment: What happens is- 1.Airport icon flashes for half a second. 2. When pushpin is created near that icon the icon goes away. I dont want this to happen.. is there any way out?

Comment: The M in liteMode should be a capital.

Comment: Yes it was capital. Well thanks a lot for guiding about vector labels. Thank you.